# Dynamically change height based on background image flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Fiddle:

https://codepen.io/0akd0adk0asdk09asd/pen/QWbaLZa

When the browser is resized, the images are being correctly resized, and the width is changing correctly, but the height is not changing at all. If I remove height: 375px; the box collapses. How do I make the height responsive like the width currently is?

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">c</div>
    <div class="bc">g</div>

  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  min-height: 375px;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.card {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/q8WyDB6.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  max-width: 148px;
  max-height: 375px;

  min-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.card::after {
  content: "";
}

.t {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.tl {
  min-height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

.tr {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;

}

.mc {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
}

.bc {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .1);
  padding: 1.0rem 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Please reopen this question, the linked answer does not work in this context at all.

Answer (score 0):

Add align-items: flex-start to to the container. By default it's strech.

stretch (default): stretch to fill the container (still respect min-width/max-width)
flex-start / start / self-start: items are placed at the start of the cross axis.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me unfortunately, could you provide a code/pen fiddle of the example? adding align-items: flex-start causes this to happen https://i.imgur.com/7PSfc8G.png when removing the height: 375px;